# Un/availability of epsilon and varepsilon in gnuplot

Tags: label, gnuplot

I have been trying to get correct 'epsilon' symbol for labeling the axes in the gnuplots. From my understanding TeXdistinguishes between two types of epsilon symbols: one is ε (varepsilon) and the other one is ϵ (epsilon). The latter one seems unavailable in gnuplot or I am not able to find a correct way out. And I want to use this one in my labels. Do I have to change to a particular font type where this is available? I tried some of the available font types but nothing worked.

I have used ϵ extensively in my document and suddenly I am a bit reluctant to use replace all in the TeX just for a single plot . Anyhow, I am also curious to know whether or not gnuplot got 'em both. Thanx in advance.

Comment: If you use `epslatex` or `cairolatex` terminal then you can use the very same font like in your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ϵ is Unicode U+03F5 GREEK LUNATE EPSILON SYMBOL

ε is Unicode U+03B5 GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON

Gnuplot is happy to work in UTF-8, so use of either or both is fine so long as you use a font that contains the corresponding glyphs.

As noted in a previous response, if you use one of gnuplot's LaTeX terminals for output (epslatex cairolatex tikz context) the text is passed to LaTeX for processing so you would use the TeX names.